# How can you create a circular pillow?

Tags: modeling

I want to create a circular pillow. I know how to make a rectangular pillow, but can't figure out a circular pillow. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should start with an idea, what pillow exactly you want to make. You could imagine it in detail, sketch it or find an example. There are [thousands of kinds of circular pillows made out of thousands of kinds of materials](https://www.google.com/search?&q=circular+pillow&tbm=isch) so it's first important to know how the one you want looks exactly.

Comment: Could you edit the question and attach an example of the kind of pillow you want to make?

Comment: Hello, katehd24. Please illustrate with a reference pillow, to make this post less vulnerable to being closed as 'unclear'.

Answer (score 4):

You could create a cylinder, scale it on Z, inset the top and bottom faces (<kbd>i</kbd>):

[image]

Bevel the top and bottom edges (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>B</kbd>):

[image]

Add loopcuts (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>R</kbd>):

[image]

Give it a *Subdivision Surface* modifier, apply the modifier to have more topology, assign the center (top and bottom) to a vertex group (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>G</kbd> > *Assign to New Group*):

[image]

Give it a *Cloth* simulation (here with *Silk* presets, enable *Pressure*, under *Shape > Pin Group* select the vertex group that you've created, enable *Self Collisions*, under *Field Weights* disable the *Gravity*):

[image]

Then you can apply the *Cloth* modifier and add details in *Sculpt* mode (here the Crease brush):

[image]

Comment: Thank you this is very helpful! I am very new to blender, could you please explain how you got the first step down 'create this mesh, assign the center (top and bottom) to a vertex group' - e.g. how do you create the mesh etc.

Comment: I've edited my answer, I hope it makes things easier?

Comment: thank you so much!!